# Angular 6 page gets redirects to homepage without doing any router methods

Tags: angular, datatables, angular-datatables

[Video rec of Issue I'm facing](https://www.loom.com/share/273bba5ebad74d6ab510579af23d926c)

I'm using jquery datatable in my angular 6 application. If I use the table in home page the table loads perfectly. But if I try to use the same table in different component and try to route to that page the view initiates for few sec and then it automatically redirected to home page. If I hide the table on that component the routing works perfectly. I don't see any error or warning in my console. so I couldn't able to find what is the source of the problem. someone kindly help me out.

**home-page.component.html**
`<p>
  home-page works!
</p>
<div [routerLink]="['/transactions']">Table</div>`

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { TransactionsComponent } from './transactions/transactions.component';
import { HomePageComponent } from './home-page/home-page.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'transactions', component: TransactionsComponent },
  { path: '', component: HomePageComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**stackblitz url**
[Issue I'm Facing](https://angular-datatable-redirect.stackblitz.io)

[Editor url](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datatable-redirect)

Comment: Can you please share your routing file for more clearance?

Comment: /* import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { TransactionsComponent } from './transactions/transactions.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'transactions', component: TransactionsComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { } */

This is my route module

Comment: Please update the file in the question rather in a comment

Answer (score 0):

You need to set default path for your application

Replace your routing as follows:

```
const routes: Routes = [{  path: '', component: **add home component here** },
   { path: 'transactions', component: TransactionsComponent }];
```

when you navigate to transaction page add slash(/) before routing tag as follows

```
[routerLink]="['/transactions']"
```

Comment: Even I added the default path it will not redirects to **transactions** path.

Comment: share your code from where you navigate to transaction page

Comment: **app.routing.module.ts**
`const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'transactions', component: TransactionsComponent },
  { path: '', component: TransactionsComponent },
];`

**app.component.html**
`<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<div [routerLink]="['/transactions']"  >Table</div>`

Comment: In your routing, For default page as well as transaction page you are navigating to the same page . please make sure what is your home component and set home component for default one

Comment: [Issue link] (https://www.loom.com/share/0483b9f21cbd43a0bb68d7c934e40109)
See the issue I'm facing @Sneha Pawar

Comment: **app.routing**
`const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'transactions', component: TransactionsComponent },
  { path: '', component: HomePageComponent },
];`

**home-page.component.html**
`<p>
  home-page works!
</p>
<div [routerLink]="['/transactions']">Table</div>`

https://www.loom.com/share/273bba5ebad74d6ab510579af23d926c

Even i added some different component as home component it will gives the same issue

Comment: You are doing something wrong. create application on stackblitz.com

Comment: This is my stackblitz. See the issue I'm facing
https://angular-datatable-redirect.stackblitz.io

editor url -- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datatable-redirect

Comment: Hi I corrected my issue. I wrongly put the authorisation check so only page gets redirected to the homepage